# Avoid console clipping/capping in ConEmu

Tags: conemu, git-bash

I'm using ConEmu with Git Bash. Everything works fine for the moment, but when I'm using tailing logs (like with Heroku using heroku logs --tail), at a certain moment the console gets clipped/capped and old entries are lost.

This doesn't happen when using Git Bash directly, so I'm guessing it's something with ConEmu.

Does anyone know if I should tweak a setting or something to avoid entries being clipped? I searched in the preferences but I couldn't find anything, but perhaps I didn't see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConEmu does not clip anything. It just shows the contents of the [RealConsole](http://conemu.github.io/en/RealConsole.html).
You may increase backscroll length of the buffer up to 32766 lines:
http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsSizePos.html#id2894

Comment: Thank you very much, Maximus! And thanks a lot for creating ConEmu, it's an amazing program! :)